# How to get image blob from OverGridImage?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have images in the google spreadsheet and want to send them through email.
Is there any way to get the blob of the images in a given sheet?

Answer (score 1):

### Unfortunately so far it is not possible

See the [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/119800855) for it on Google's Public Issue Tracker.

**Background**

`OverGridImage` is a rather new feature, programmatically only the [following](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/over-grid-image) method have been implemented for it so far. The interface to [BlobSource](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob-source)
is unfortunately not one of them.

**What you can do**

"Star" the feature request - this will increase its visibility and it is more likely that Google will implement it soon.

Comment: Thanks @ziganotschka,
I have raised a feature request with Google. It seems that it has been assigned to dev as I got mail asking about "why I want it, the impact of this feature on my task' ect.

Comment: There is already the existing feature request I linked in my answer. You should "star" it or comment on it rather than creating a new one, because a new request for the same feature will likely be marked as a duplicate by Google.